# is it efficent to use spacer in flexbox

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I have 4 div's and i want two of these left of the container and other two on the right.

i manage to do it with like this do you think is that a good aproach in tailwind-css or in general?

```css
div.flex {
    background-color: #eee;
    outline: 1px solid #999;
}

div.flex > * {
    background-color: #ccc;
    outline: 1px solid #333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.2"></script>

<div class="sticky w-full h-16 gap-2 flex items-center">
    <div class="ml-4 w-8 h-8"></div>
    <div class="w-8 h-8"></div>
    <div class="grow"></div>
    <div class="w-8 h-8"></div>
    <div class="mr-4 w-8 h-8"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, HTML elements should not be introduced to add styles. Your HTML code should only reflect your content and CSS should be used to style/position your elements.

Use `ml-auto` on the third element

```css
div.flex {
    background-color: #eee;
    outline: 1px solid #999;
}

div.flex > * {
    background-color: #ccc;
    outline: 1px solid #333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.2"></script>

<div class="sticky w-full h-16 gap-2 flex items-center">
    <div class="ml-4 w-8 h-8"></div>
    <div class="w-8 h-8"></div>
    <div class="w-8 h-8 ml-auto"></div> 
    <div class="mr-4 w-8 h-8"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: That looks like perfect and cleanest solution thank youu

Answer (score 1):

(Disclaimer: I am not a Tailwind user, so I don't know if using spacer elements is *idiomatic* in Tailwind or not - but if this were my own project I'd avoid them: simpler HTML with fewer moving-parts is more maintainable, imo)

You don't need any placeholder elements in your HTML - you can use CSS's flexbox's built-in support for customizing element location and spacing using `margin: auto`, like so:

```css
div.flex {
    background-color: #eee;
    outline: 1px solid #999;
}

div.flex > * {
    background-color: #ccc;
    outline: 1px solid #333;
}

div.flex > *:nth-child(2) {
    margin-right: auto;
}
div.flex > *:nth-child(3) {
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.2"></script>

<div class="sticky w-full h-16 gap-2 flex items-center">
    <div class="ml-4 w-8 h-8"></div>
    <div class="w-8 h-8"></div>
    <div class="w-8 h-8"></div>
    <div class="mr-4 w-8 h-8"></div>
</div>
```

---

An alternative approach is to use two child flex containers, with the grandparent flex container having `justify-content: space-between;`:

Also, instead of using explicit margins via `.ml-4` and `.mr-4` (which set `margin-left/right: 1rem;` respectively) consider just using `gap: 1rem;`:

```css
div#grandparent {
    background-color: #eee;
    outline: 1px solid #999;

    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 1rem;
}
div#grandparent > div.flex {
    background-color: #ddd;

    flex-shrink: 1;
    gap: 1rem;
}
div#grandparent > div.flex > * {
    background-color: #ccc;
    outline: 1px solid #333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.2"></script>

<div class="sticky w-full h-16 gap-2 flex items-center" id="grandparent">
    <div class="flex">
        <div class="w-8 h-8"></div>
        <div class="w-8 h-8"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex">
        <div class="w-8 h-8"></div>
        <div class="w-8 h-8"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah this approach is very good thanks. Also ml-4 and mr-4 means 1rem in tailwind css its not fix value or gap-2 h-16 these all rem but px but 2 flex div's with space-between is great idea.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, using a spacer element is an efficient approach in flexbox. Your code seems to be correctly placing two divs on the left and two divs on the right, with a spacer in between. It's a good practice to use flexbox and leverage the `gap` utility in Tailwind CSS for spacing.

Comment: Considering that CSS flex-box does not normally need spacers (because `margin: auto;` and `justify-*` properties achieve the same effect) **why** do you say it's "good practice"? .